# working with git on a ubuntu server

Tags: windows, macos, git, ubuntu

I have a small network of machines (2 windows, 2 macs, 1 ubuntu server and 1 fedora). I was wondering if any once could help me with how I should set git up so I can push and pull files both locally and remotely. However I do not want to use github.

So ideally i would like to have git installed on my ubuntu server and then be able to pull and push from my other machines.

So far i have managed to install git on my ubuntu server. init a folder and add/commit files in said folder. Im not too sure on how I can get my other machines to pull and push to this server.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: There is nothing to set up, if all machines have SSH access to the server. Use the `ssh://` protocol to access your repo and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push, then you should use a bare repository. On the Ubuntu server, from your home directory, do:

```
git init --bare myrepo.git
```

Then on the other servers, just:

```
git clone username@my-ubuntu-server:myrepo.git
```

Then pull and push should just work. Use an IP address instead of `my-ubuntu-server` if you don't have DNS set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the way described by Robie Basak. If you want to have more fine grained control, you can install the [`gitolite`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gitolite) package. See e.g. [here](http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/04/29/ubuntu-12-dot-04-installing-gitolite-and-gitweb/) for a step-by-step introduction. You might also want to review the *very* extensive [documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html). If you also want to have bug tracking, code review, wiki and pull requests, take a look at [gitlab](http://gitlab.org/).